# How to remove disable breakpoints I did not set?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

While debugging I get breakpoints from code that is not mine and for breakpoints I have not set.
Either it seems to come from libraries included or from java source code somehow.
Example:

[image]

Question:
This is really annoying. I can not find a way to disable these breakpoints and I keep pressing Resume constantly to move on.
How can I remove them or disable them? The breakpoint tab shows only my breakpoints available to be skipped or deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unset the following parameter in Eclipse:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions
```

Comment: Brilliant! Had no idea about this configuration.Thanks a lot!